# Multibyte Characters Between Java and Python (UnicodeEncodeError)

Tags: java, python, unicode, multibyte

I currently am developing a Django app that calls to a Java REST API and retrieves multilingual results (the results are coming from Elasticsearch to begin with). I can retrieve the results and store them into an object just fine, but displaying them within Javascript is giving me junk - this is supposed to be Russian:

[image: a junk]

When converting it to a string or trying to convert to unicode, I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /getObjectArticles
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 23-24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know the API is returning good data because calling with a Java app works fine. Any idea how to handle the incoming string so it will be recognizable characters?

EDIT: My ingest code..

```
g = requests.post(baseUrl, query_string)

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e

try:
    obj = g.json()
    articleTitle = obj['hit']['title']
    str(articleTitle)   # This results in a Unicode error
    articleTitle.decode("UTF-8")   # This results in a Unicode error
```

EDIT: My Javascript/JQUERY

```
// Load article text
function getArticleText(articleId, index) {
    console.log($('#result_number').val());
    var es_url = gu.webapp_url + '/getArticle?articleId=' + encodeURIComponent(articleId) + "&index=" + encodeURIComponent(index);

    $.get(es_url).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var decodedText = $("<div/>").html(data.text).text();
        var decodedTitle = $("<div/>").html(data.articleTitle).text();

        // Close Article View Button
        $('#g2i2-article-info').html("<div id=\"closeArticleInfo\" class=\"closeWindow\">X</div>");

        // Article Info Table
        var articleTable = "<table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed\">";
        articleTable = articleTable + "<tr><td>Title</td><td>" + decodedTitle + "</td></tr>";
        articleTable = articleTable + "<tr><td>Publication Date</td><td>" + data.pubDate + "</td></tr>";
        articleTable = articleTable + "<tr><td>Source Name</td><td>" + data.sourceName + "</td></tr>";
        articleTable = articleTable + "<tr><td>Location</td><td>" + data.locationName + "</td></tr>";
        articleTable = articleTable + "<tr><td>URL</td><td>" + data.url + "</td></tr>";
        articleTable = articleTable + "</table>"
        $('#g2i2-article-info').append(articleTable);

        // Article Text
        $('#g2i2-article-info').append(decodedText);
        $('#g2i2-article-info').css('display', 'block');

    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    });

}
```

Comment: Yippee, that's a Latin-1 Mojibake. Your browser is displaying UTF-8 data as Latin 1 instead. Which explains why the ASCII codepoints are still readable too.

Comment: The `UnicodeEncodeError` just means you are trying to convert Unicode *back to Unicode*, meaning it is being auto-encoded by Python to ASCII first just so you can decode. You *already* have Unicode. It is the browser output that fails here.

Comment: Take the `Ð¡` combination at the start of your title, for example. That's really UTF-8 `D0` `A1`, or [`С` U+0421 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES](http://codepoints.net/U+0421).

Comment: JSON data is always decoded to Unicode objects *already*. Trying to decode a Unicode value triggers an implicit **encode** to ASCII first. The problem lies in your browser page, your *browser* is told to use Latin 1 to read the page, but you put UTF-8 data in it.

Comment: `str(articleTitle)` *also* includes an implicit encode. Django on the other hand can encode Unicode to a browser page just fine. That all works. What headers does Django send to the browser? Specifically, what is the `Content-Type` header? Is there a `<meta>` tag in the page that tells the browser what content type to use?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Here's my return. I thought my 'Content-Type' was handling UTF-8 properly, but apparently not?    
    r = HttpResponse(s)
    r['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Comment: Where 's' is my JSON naturally.

Comment: That's not what I asked you for. That's for the JSON data. You posted a screenshot of a *browser page*. What was sent to that browser?

Comment: *Your browser* is handed UTF-8 encoded data, but is displaying it as if it is Latin 1 text instead. That is what is going wrong here. Nothing on the server is wrong unless you are explicitly telling the browser the page is Latin 1 somewhere.

Comment: I've added my JS that loads the browser, and I do have <meta charset="utf-8"> in my header.

Comment: And you are sending the Unicode data from the JSON response *unaltered* to the browser? Or do you encode it at any point?

Comment: Does the text look correct in your *browser console*?

Comment: Also, what does `print repr(articleTitle)` show? I am trying to make sure you didn't receive Mojibaked data.

Comment: I've cut out the Java API temporarily, so I'm grabbing data directly from Elasticsearch now. The print repr(articleTitle) for a Russian example is giving: u'\u0412 \u0430\u0440\u0441\u0435\u043d\u0430\u043b\u0435

Comment: The code also looks good in the console. It needs to be something while displaying it to the browser. I'm not doing anything to the data, getting it from the $.get() call and putting it directly into a table.

Comment: Ah, it WAS something from the API. It looks like things are working now that I'm going directly from Elasticsearch. I guess I'll have to look into the encoding discrepancy from the API to Django.

Comment: `articleTitle` looks correct -- it is a Unicode string that starts with "В арсенале...". Do not call `str()` on a Unicode string, do not call `.decode()` on Unicode string. If you need to encode Unicode string into bytes then call `bytestring = unicode_string.encode(character_encoding)`. Most probably you should not do anything with the Unicode string just pass it to django as is; it will encode it to bytes by itself before sending it to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have Unicode data on your server; `response.json()` produces Unicode values for any JSON string. There is no need to try and decode it.

It is the *browser* that is producing this [Latin 1 Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). The browser is sent UTF-8 (a multi-byte encoding) and the browser is interpreting *individual bytes* as Latin 1 characters instead. Your title, for example, starts with the Cyrilic text `Со`, which is encoded to UTF-8, then misinterpreted as Latin 1:

```
>>> u'Со'
u'\u0421\u043e'
>>> u'Со'.encode('utf8')
'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbe'
>>> print u'Со'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
Ð¡Ð¾
```

So the `D0` `A1` bytes in UTF-8, which form *one codepoint*, are being printed as two Latin-1 characters instead.

The `Ñ` character is the `D1` byte, which can be followed by about 33 non-printable second UTF-8 bytes to make a character in the range `р` through to `Ѡ`. Next is `Ð¸` which is really `и`, etc.

You need to figure out why the *browser* thinks your data is Latin 1.

Usually this is determined from the `Content-Type` header sent to the browser; if it is set to `text/html; charset=ISO-8851-1` then the browser will behave as if all text is Latin 1. It could be the HTML page has a `<meta>` tag, one of `<meta charset="ISO-8851-1">` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="ISO-8851-1">` or similar, where there are several closely related encodings that all have similar Mojibake effects.

Another option is that you encoded it to UTF-8 explicitly, then managed to decode it somewhere to Latin-1 again before sending it to the browser.

And a 3rd option is that the JSON service you used itself sent you Latin-1 bytes in a JSON unicode string, giving you a Mojibake source. In that case you can still repair it by encoding to Latin 1 then decoding from UTF-8:

```
fixed = broken.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

but do so only after you have verified that your data on the server is already Mojibaked.